# My Table is not re-rendering even it is calling useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, dom-events

`directoryList` is a state of the list which consist of file details (`filename,keyword,status,checked`) in one of my component.

My Whole code is added in [codesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-sunset-s9k35?file=/src/App.js)

Instruction:

1. Add one text file and click upload
2. Give one word in keyword input box and
   give numerical value in default Lines
3. Click "Apply for Checked
4. Click "Find" button

```
directoryList = [{
filename:'',
checked: false,
keyword:'',
linestoBecopied:0,
status:""
}]
```

I have one button called `Find`. if I click the button, `findButtonHandler` will be called.

Here I am trying to change the status, value is changing but UI is not re-rendered. If I click `Find` button two times, the UI is re-rendered.

```
   
   useEffect(() => {
     console.log("useEffect called")
    }, [directoryList]);


      const fileChangeHandler = (e) =>
      {
        const files=[]
        console.log("hiiiii")
        for(let i = 0; i< e.target.files.length; i++) {
          files.push(e.target.files[i])
      }
      console.log(files)
      setFiles(files)
    }
      const uploadClickHandler=()=>
      {
        var list=[];
        for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++ )
        {
        var file = files[i];
        console.log(file.name)
        var obj = {
          filename: file.name,
          status:"",
          checked:true,
            keyWord:"",
            linesToBeCopied:""
        }
        list.push(obj);
      }
        setDirectoryList([...list])
        console.log(directoryList)
      
      }

      const applyForCheckHandler = () =>
      {
        const list = [...directoryList]
        list.map((dir,i) => (
          dir.keyWord=keyWord,
          dir.linesToBeCopied=defLines
        ))
        console.log(list)
        setDirectoryList([...list])
        
      }

      const checkBoxHandler = (filename) =>
      {
        console.log("hi")
        var list1 = directoryList
        list1.map((dir,i) => {
          if(i==filename)
          {
          if(dir.checked==true)
           dir.checked=false
          else
           dir.checked=true 
        }})
        console.log(list1)
        setDirectoryList(list1)
      }

      **const findButtonHandler = () =>
      {
        let list1 = [...directoryList]
        for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++)
        {
          let status=""
          var file = files[i]
          list1.map((dir,i) => {
            if(dir.filename==file.name && dir.checked)
            {
              
               var reader = new FileReader();
               reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
               var lines = this.result.split('\n');
               for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
                 console.log(lines[line])
                 if(lines[line].includes(dir.keyWord)){
                   console.log("text found")
                   status = "Found"
                   dir.status = "Found"
                   break;
                   }
                 else{
                  status="Not Found"
                  dir.status = status
                 }
              }
            };  reader.readAsText(file);
            }
         
        })}
        console.log(list1)
        
      }**

      const saveHandler = () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        var str = JSON.stringify(directoryList)
        var list = JSON.parse(str);
        var list1 = directoryList
        var filename=""
        console.log(directoryList.length)
        list1.map((dir,i) => {
          console.log(dir.filename+dir.checked)
          if(dir.checked==true && dir.status=='Found')
            filename = filename + dir.filename + ","
        })
        var lines = defLines
        var keyword = keyWord

        for(let i = 0; i< files.length; i++) {
          formData.append('file', files[i])
        }
        formData.append("lines",lines)
        formData.append("keyword",keyword)
        formData.append("filenames",filename)
        
        console.log(lines)
        console.log(keyWord)
        console.log(filename)

        axios.post('http://localhost:8080/save', formData,{
          headers:{
          "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
         } })
        .then((response) => {
          fileDownload(response.data,'output.txt')
         
        }).catch(error =>
          {
            console.log(error.message)
          });
      }
    return (
        <>
        <HeadingComponent>
            <h3>Data Quest</h3>
        </HeadingComponent>
        <FirstComponent>
          <SearchDirComponent>
        Select Filesto Upload : <input type='file' name="files" id="inputfile" onChange={fileChangeHandler} multiple></input>
        </SearchDirComponent>
       <FirstButtonComponent>
       <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="default"
        startIcon={<CloudUploadIcon />}
        onClick={uploadClickHandler}
      >
        Upload
      </Button>
      <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="secondary"
        startIcon={<DeleteIcon />}
      >
        Close
      </Button>
       </FirstButtonComponent>
         
        </FirstComponent>
        <SecondComponent>
          <SecondInputComponent>
        <div> Search Keyword :  <OutlinedInput type='text' name="directoryname"  value={keyWord} onChange={(e)=> setkeyword(e.target.value)}style = {{width: 100,height:30,paddingLeft:10}}></OutlinedInput></div>
        <div style={{paddingLeft:150}}> Default Lines <OutlinedInput type='text' name="defaultLines" value={defLines} onChange={(e)=> setDefLines(e.target.value)} style = {{width: 100,height:30,paddingLeft:10}}></OutlinedInput></div>
        <div style={{paddingLeft:150}}>
        <Button
        variant="contained"
        color="primary"
        onClick={applyForCheckHandler}
        style={{fontSize:14 ,width:220,height:27}}
      >
        Apply for checked
      </Button>
        </div>
        </SecondInputComponent>
        <ApplyButtonComponent>
        
        </ApplyButtonComponent>
        </SecondComponent>
       <TableComponent> 
    <TableContainer component={Paper}>
      <Table aria-label="simple table">
        <TableHead>
          <TableRow>
            <TableCell align="center">&nbsp;&nbsp;Select Files</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">File Name</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">Search Keyword&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">Lines to be copied&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
            <TableCell align="center">Status&nbsp;(g)</TableCell>
          </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
          {directoryList.length>0 && directoryList.map((directory,i) => (
            <TableRow key={directory.filename}>
              <TableCell component="th" scope="row" align="center">
               <Checkbox checked={directory.checked} onClick={() => checkBoxHandler(i)} name={directory.filename}></Checkbox></TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{directory.filename}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{directory.keyWord}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{directory.linesToBeCopied}</TableCell>
              <TableCell align="center">{directory.status}</TableCell>
            </TableRow>
          ))}
        </TableBody>
      </Table>
    </TableContainer>
        </TableComponent>
        { directoryList.length >0 &&
        
        <ButtonComponent>
          <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" onClick={findButtonHandler}>
        Find
        </Button></div>
        <div>
        <Button variant="contained" color="primary" style={{paddingLeft: 20}} onClick={saveHandler}>
        Save
       </Button></div>
        </ButtonComponent>} 
        </>
    )
}
```

Comment: where is your button to called ```findButtonHandler``` method ?

Comment: @edhi.uchiha i just added another few lines of code

Comment: You may be missing the return statement, can you share the complete code

Comment: Can you please share code in code sandbox??

Comment: @AjithRam please check my answer

Comment: @MuhammadBilalBangash@Vijayaraghavan Sundararaman i added my whole code in sand box

Comment: I think you have to be more clear with your question. It is a little difficult to understand because of its complexity.

Comment: You say that status is changing but UI is not. I clicked Find one time and nothing changed not the UI and also not the status.

Comment: @TusharShahi sorry for the inconvenience. i given the link for code sand box and also instruction. please try

Answer (score 1):

I see here because your state called `directoryList` is never changed so your component not triggering re-render.

Please try to change your `directoryList` state like this :

```
  const findButtonHandler = () => {
    let list1 = [...directoryList]

     for(let i=0;i<files.length;i++)
     {
       let status=""
       var file = files[i]
       list1.map((dir,i) => {
         if(dir.filename==file.name && dir.checked) {

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(progressEvent){
            var lines = this.result.split('\n');
            for(var line = 0; line < lines.length; line++){
              console.log(lines[line])
              if(lines[line].includes(dir.keyWord)){
                console.log("text found")
                status = "Found"
                dir.status = "Found"
                break;
                }
              else{
               status="Not Found"
               dir.status = status
              }
           }
         };  reader.readAsText(file);
         }

         list1[i].status = status // add this line
     }
     )}
     console.log(list1)
    setDirectoryList([...list1]);
  };
```

And see the result, and remember that re-render will triggered just when your state is changed. If you used hook you have to declared the state you want to triggering calling useEffect at the array.

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log("useEffect called")
    }, [directoryList]);
```

`useEffect` will called or re-render the component when value of `directoryList` is changed

Comment: Status is not a single variable. in DirectoryList, each file may have different status

Comment: see, when i clicking Find Button, useEffect is called and able to see the changes in state with the help of console.log

Comment: @AjithRam please check my updated answer, I guess you can add ```list1[i].status = status```

Comment: Please check this for details example https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-breeze-qnu13?file=/src/App.js

Comment: list1[i].status = status is not worked , the status value is not printed in UI but if i hardcode like list1[i].status='found', it printing

Comment: Em please check your condition, is the value of status changed ? or just empty string ```""```

Comment: i am changing status inside asynchronous function. That is the issue

Answer (score 0):

reader.onload() is asynchronous function so that the status value is not changed at the first time